# Can't stop AVPlayer streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerlayer, avplayerview

I have a `UITableview` with an `AVPlayer` instance  in every cell. My requirement is to stream video only in the visible cells hence I don't want any player instances in the invisible cells. Play method is called in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.
 Here is my code to remove AVPlayer

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell: (UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
 {
    if (![ _feedsTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
        NSLog(@"index of visible cell  %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
        LTHomeFeedCell * cell = (LTHomeFeedCell*)[_feedsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ];
        [ cell.avMoviePlayer pause ];
        cell.avMoviePlayer = [ AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""] ];
        cell.avMoviePlayer = nil;
  }
```

But, still I hear audio from invisible cells. I'm using this same code to pause the video when I move to a different screen but I still hear the audio. How do I fix this?

Comment: You have to stream multiple videos at once? why not use only one `AVplayer` and change its `AVPlayerLayer` to the cells as needed?

Comment: i @BenjaminJimenez could you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the pause function through local notifications also like this:

- Add an observer for a local notification in the cell when you start playing the video.
- And in the selector of that notification, write the code to pause you player and remove the notification
- After that in didEndDisplayingCell, post that notification to pause that video.

Comment: My issue the even after pausing and making the player instance nil i still hear audio and video stream continuous.